# Renaming columns in Snowflake SQL while using Common Table Expressions

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have data in Snowflake in following format;

```
ID |    1     |  2  
123|2019-11-30|2019-12-01
234|2019-11-29|2019-12-12
```

Is it possible to get data in following format;

```
ID|Click1|Click2
123|2019-11-30|2019-12-01
234|2019-11-29|2019-12-12
```

I tried to use the following code;

```
... ,col_rename AS( SELECT member_sk
                   ,1 AS "click1"
                   ,2 AS "click2"

FROM pivoted
ORDER BY ID)
```

But I m getting following output;

```
ID|Click1|Click2
123|1|2
234|1|2
```

Am not sure why are the date values disappearing? Can I kindly get some help.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date values are disappearing because you are selecting the constants `1` and `2`.

For these to be recognized as column names, try double quotes:

```
select member_sk, "1" as click1, "2" as click2
from pivoted;
```

Better yet, qualify the names so the meaning is quite clear:

```
select p.member_sk, p."1" as click1, p."2" as click2
from pivoted p;
```

Comment: thanks for the solution.it did work.treating them as strings helped.

Comment: @jayant . . . They are NOT strings.  They are escaped identifiers.  If you want a string, use single quotes.